# Twig framework and datetime errors

Tags: mysql, frameworks, php, twig

I'm running an events site - powered by PHP/MySQL, on Apache 2.28.
I can get the HTML table to display as per http://devzone.zend.com/article/13633.

For this site on localhost, I'm using the Twig framework mentioned at www. twig-project. org

The content is extracted from a local MySQL database:

My code:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }        
      tr.heading {      
        font-weight: bolder;
      }        
      td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 0 0.5em;
      }    
    </style>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Events</h2>
    <table>
      <tr class="heading">
        <td>Event time</td>
        <td>Event name</td>
      </tr> 
      {% for d in data %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ d.evtime|escape }}</td>
        <td>{{ d.evname|escape }}</td>
      </tr> 
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

// The PHP file is below

```
    <?php
// include and register Twig auto-loader
include 'Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

// attempt a connection
try {
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=world;host=localhost', 'root', 'MYPASS');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage();
}

// set error mode
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// attempt some queries
try {
  // execute SELECT query
  // store each row as an object
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM myeventdb";
  $sth = $dbh->query($sql);
  while ($row = $sth->fetchObject()) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }

  // close connection, clean up
  unset($dbh); 

  // define template directory location
  $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');

  // initialize Twig environment
  $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

  // load template
  $template = $twig->loadTemplate('countries.tmpl');

  // set template variables
  // render template
  echo $template->render(array (
    'data' => $data
  ));

} catch (Exception $e) {
  die ('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

However, I can't get the datetime to display as this for my events:
1:30pm Geography Class

Instead it displays as
13:30:00 Geography Class

Why is this, and what do I need to fix it, within the Twig syntax?
I'm fairly new to this, and I had a look through the documentation but there wasn't much on the site about it.

Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

So the script is displaying 13:30:00 because that's what's coming out of the database - you're not formatting the date anywhere.

In your Twig template, you can use a [`date` filter](http://www.twig-project.org/doc/templates.html#date) to format the date to your liking, according to the [PHP `date` function formatting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
{{ d.evtime|date('g:ia')|escape }}
```

If you wanted to do the formatting beforehand, just use a combination of `date` and `strtotime`:

```
$formatted_time = date('g:ia',strtotime($unformatted_time));
```